# How to compare power towers in Mathematica?

Tags: evaluation, numerics, wolfram-alpha-queries, big-numbers

First I tried it directly, but it overflowed:

```
In[1]:= 2^3^2^3^5^8 < 3^2^2^7^6^7
During evaluation of In[1]:= General::ovfl: Overflow occurred in computation. >>
During evaluation of In[1]:= General::ovfl: Overflow occurred in computation. >>

Out[1]= Indeterminate < Indeterminate
```

Using double `Log` did not help either:

```
In[2]:= Log[Log[2]] + Log[3] 2^3^5^8 < Log[Log[3]] + Log[2] 2^7^6^7  
During evaluation of In[2]:= General::ovfl: Overflow occurred in computation. >>
During evaluation of In[2]:= General::ovfl: Overflow occurred in computation. >>

Out[2]= Overflow[] < Overflow[]
```

Then I tried to use the [`WolframAlpha`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/WolframAlpha.html) function, and it seemed to be able to handle this and even much higher towers:

```
In[3]:= WolframAlpha["2^3^2^3^5^8 < 3^2^2^7^6^7", "MathematicaForms"][[2, 1]]
Out[3]= True

In[4]:= WolframAlpha["2^2^5^2^7^4^9^3^7^6^9^9^9^9^3^2 < 3^3^6^3^9^4^2^3^2^2^2^2^2^3^3^3", "MathematicaForms"][[2, 1]]
Out[4]= True
```

But then I discovered that it failed to perform certain comparisons:

```
In[5]:= WolframAlpha["4^6^8^8^9 < 3^2^3^3^3", "MathematicaForms"]
Out[5]= {}
```

And sometimes even gave wrong answers, even in seemingly trivial cases:

```
In[6]:= WolframAlpha["3^3^3^3^3 < 4^4^3^3^3", "MathematicaForms"][[2, 1]]
Out[6]= False
```

Can anybody suggest a correct and robust method to compare two expressions given in the form `Hold[a^b^...^z]`, where `a,b,...,z` are positive integers?

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4696882/solving-power-towers/) question.

Comment: Just because it caused me a lot of consternation, [the top answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/101138/complexity-class-of-comparison-of-power-towers) on the Math Stack Exchange is [mathematically incorrect](http://codeforces.com/blog/entry/4571).

Comment: @Guillochon Both are incorrect and misleading as it is also pointed out in comments. Strange thing that they are sill there.

Comment: Am I guessing wrong if I say that if the towers are high enough and your integers are all small, then comparing the heights first and if equal then comparing top-down is "reasonable"?

Comment: @Kuba Let's downvote them.

Comment: @Rojo, I don't know what do You mean by comparing top-down but it seems that with Yours assumptions what matters is couple (3 or 4) exponents on the top (or, the most internal, in terms of order of evaluations). This is consistent with answer given by Leonid.

Comment: @Kuba I meant what seem to have understood. I'm assuming WolphramAlpha handles those numbers in an inexact representation.

Comment: Just like float's accuracy decreases as the number goes big, in a representation where you have a few bits to fit such a huuuge range of numbers it must decrease like crazy. So, numbers with same height and top exponents might be seen as equal (4^4^3^3^3 vs 3^3^3^3^3). Given that they are in WA, I wonder if they are coming in MMA10

Comment: @Rojo Even if they might be seen as equal in some representations, there is actually a huge difference between them: `4^4^3^3^3 - 3^3^3^3^3 > 10^10^4591067155680`.

Comment: I started a bounty worth +350 at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/101138/complexity-class-of-comparison-of-power-towers

Comment: @VladimirReshetnikov This is really nice. I saw the answers yesterday, because my first thought was (too), let the mathematicians do the job and just implement it. What I saw there was really embarrassing for math.SE especially, because the obviously wrong answers were neither downloaded nor deleted. Let's hope the bounty attracts some more creative people and not only those, who don't even know the laws of exponentiation.

Comment: @halirutan Nobody is responsible for deleting incorrect answers: signaling such problems is the role of downvotes. (On other sites, including math.SE, misunderstandings over this issue have created great amounts of angst among some people who have mistakenly accused moderators of not doing their jobs and have disparaged the communities. Please let's not foster such misunderstanding here.)

Comment: I hate that expressions like `4^4^3^3^3` totally freeze my computer instead of just telling me to stop trying evaluating this and quietly abort :(.

Comment: Some sort of an digit extraction (or similar) algorithm that would decide on every iteration whether one power tower (or monotonic transformation of it) is larger, smaller, or still unknown in comparison to another would be very interesting. Complexity of this is quite interesting; clearly relatively "simple" tower pairs should exhibit conditions (values close to each other) that make it impossible to compute the result with time or storage resources of our universe. Most of pairs are much easier, and another funny part is that you can't really list those that are "very hard!" (No proof here.)

Answer (score 23):

#### The idea

The idea is that if we have

$\log(a+b),\qquad a\gg b$ ,

then we can equivalently write this as

$\log a + \log(1 + b/a)$

and the second part will be small, so that one can first compare the first part(s). The power towers with base numbers larger than 1 naturally lead to such logarithms when we repeatedly take the $\log$ of them. So, there seems to be a natural separation of a dominant part and a sub-leading part, which is what I think allows one to compare the towers in many or most cases.

#### Implementation

OK, here is my attempt. To illustrate what I am going to do, first define these functions:

```
ClearAll[symbolicConvert];
SetAttributes[symbolicConvert, {HoldAll, Listable}];
symbolicConvert[num_] := Unevaluated[num] /. Power -> power
```

which replaces `Power` to `power`, and

```
ClearAll[log];
log[power[base_, exp_]] := exp * log[base];

log[HoldPattern[Times[args__]]] := Total@Map[log, {args}];

log[(main : (_log*_power)) + rest_] :=  log[main] + log[1 + rest/main];

log[main_ + rest : log[1 + _]] := log[main] + log[1 + rest/main];
```

which is a function to perform the transformation I need. Here is an illustration:

```
start = symbolicConvert[2^3^2^3^5^8]

(* power[2, power[3, power[2, power[3, power[5, 8]]]]]  *)
```

and then

```
NestList[log, start,4]
```

[image]

where I used an image since it better shows the resulting structure. The main thing to note is that the `log[1+something]` part will be small in (almost) all cases, because the "something" will be quite small. Therefore, the idea is to compare the parts in the sum which do not involve this `log`, first. If they are equal, we can compare these logs.

This function will tell us how long we will have to nest the application of `log`:

```
ClearAll[getNestingLength];
getNestingLength[expr_power] := 
   Length[{expr /. power -> Sequence}] - 1;
```

This is a helper function we will need to extract the dominant part:

```
ClearAll[getMain];
getMain[main_ + log[1 + _]] := main;
getMain[x_ /; FreeQ[x, power]] := x;
```

This function will prepare our expressions for comparison:

```
ClearAll[prep];
SetAttributes[prep, HoldAll];
prep[fst_Power, sec_Power] :=
  With[{nest = Max[getNestingLength /@ #]},
     Map[Nest[log, #, nest] &, #]] &@symbolicConvert[{fst, sec}];
```

for the first examplein the question, this will produce:

```
prep[2^3^2^3^5^8, 3^2^2^7^6^7]
```

[image]

Note that so far, everything has been exact - while we represent the logs in this form, I did not employ any approximation yet.

Here is then the comparison function, which may be a bit ad hoc and might not cover all cases, but it worked on a few I tested:

```
ClearAll[less];
less[fst_, sec_] /; And @@ Map[
          MatchQ[#, (_ + log[1 + _]) | (x_ /; FreeQ[x, power])] &, 
          {fst, sec}] && getMain[fst] =!= getMain[sec] :=
   getMain[fst] < getMain[sec] /. log -> (If[# <= 0, 0, Log[#]] &);

less[fst : (main_ + log[1 + fr_/rmain_]), sec : (main_ + log[1 + sr_/rmain_])] :=
   less[rmain + fr, rmain + sr];

less[a_log + b_/c_power, a_log + d_/c_power] := less[b, d];
```

#### Examples

```
less @@ prep[2^3^2^3^5^8, 3^2^2^7^6^7]

(* True *)

less @@ prep[10^3^4^5, 3^3^4^5]

(* False *)

less @@ prep[2^2^5^2^7^4^9^3^7^6^9^9^9^9^3^2, 3^3^6^3^9^4^2^3^2^2^2^2^2^3^3^3]

(* True *)
```

#### Remarks

It may well be that the current implementation does contain some bugs or does not cover some cases,  but I think that the main idea behind it should work. Note that my approach should work in most cases except when the bases are so huge that even their logs can overcome the powers they are divided over.

Comment: That's pretty impressive! I would like to see an example when this will fail, if it exists of course :).

Comment: @swish Oh I am sure it exists, since I have used a couple of assumptions I mentioned in the text, so my function does not have a status of a theorem. I did not have the time to elaborate on the failing conditions, but I am sure it can be done.

Comment: failing example: `less @@ prep[2^4, 4^2]`

Comment: @VladimirReshetnikov Well, in a way, that's not quite my fault: try to evaluate `4 Log[2] < 2 Log[4]` in Mathematica. I could have inserted `N` in some places to avoid that, but that would have introduced another possibility for an error due to going to inexact numbers.

Comment: @VladimirReshetnikov In fact, my function does not really fail: it returns a warning and `4 Log[2] < 2 Log[4]`, which is correct (although useless) :). Could add `FullSimplify`, then it returns `False` as it should.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin: Sure, it is not a big deal :)

Comment: @VladimirReshetnikov I am sure there are more serious bugs in my function though, e.g. for very large base numbers. This is sort of a quick and dirty first try, still needs some polishing.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin: The result seems to be incorrect (`True`) in this case: `less @@ prep[2^2^2^2^2^2^2^2^2^2^2^2^2^2^4^2^2^2, 
  9^9^9^9^9^9^9^9^9^9^9^9^9^9^9^9]`. I have not yet analyzed why.

Comment: @VladimirReshetnikov It is interesting that slightly rewriting your example `less @@ prep[2^2^2^2^2^2^2^2^2^2^2^2^2^2^4^16, 
  9^9^9^9^9^9^9^9^9^9^9^9^9^9^9^9]` gives a different result. I guess my approcimation breaks down when I take logs to many times. The "main" part of the log should be substantially larger than 1, while for this example I end up comparing `2 log[2] + log[log[2]]` and `log[log[9 log[9] + log[log[9]]]]`, both of which are really close to 1. I will add some condition for that.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin You might want to publish your algorithm or just a link to this answer at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/101138/complexity-class-of-comparison-of-power-towers The +350 bounty ends in several hours and I think your algorithm is the best from all that were suggested and it looks having a polynomial complexity.

Comment: @VladimirReshetnikov Thanks, I do appreciate. I am not currently registered on math.stackexchange though, and converting it into math notation and making the post would take some time, which I may not have today or tomorrow. Besides, I left Maths and Physics behind, at least for the immediately foreseeable future :). I might add a post there at some later point, or feel free to self-answer there based on this post.

Comment: @VladimirReshetnikov: How did you generate your testcases?

Comment: @LeonidShifrin I awarded the bounty to your answer as the best and closest to a complete solution so far. I still cannot mark it as an accepted answer because it errs on some corner cases. I hope you will find a time to make it perfect! Thanks!

Comment: @PiotrShatalin Thanks! I will keep this issue in mind. I think I know how to fix it, but I just need to find some time. Please do ping me again after some time if nothing comes from me.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin 6 years late, but I would be interested if you still remember what your fix was

Comment: @alphacapture Unfortunately I don't. The first step would be to collect (edge) cases where the current solution fails.