# Comparing large numbers

Tags: big-numbers

How can I compare **really** large numbers in *Mathematica*?

I'm trying to compare:

```
2^4^4^4 < 4^4^4^4
```

It yields:

```
Overflow[] < Overflow[]
```

But, [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%5E4%5E4%5E4%20%3C%204%5E4%5E4%5E4) compares it (incorrectly, so).

Comment: Have a look at [24815](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/24815/134)