# How to work with large numbers

Tags: number-representation, big-numbers

How do I browse very large numbers in mathematica, say $10^{{10}^{{10}^{1.414\ldots}}}$?

By browse I mean finding the $k$th decimal place before or after the decimal point. Everything I have tried has given me `overflow[]` or something equally useless.

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/24815/how-to-compare-power-towers-in-mathematica

Comment: Use the undocumented Developer`Kabbalah package. But seriously, there are limits, look at $MaxNumber on your machine. Compare that to what you're trying to generate as an exponent....

Comment: And the exponent 1.1414... is what? An approximation of `Sqrt[2]`, `1 + 14/99`, ...?

Comment: @halirutan Just a random number. It was an example.

Comment: You might try extracting logs once or twice, figuring out what digits you need from that, and exponentiating. Not sure how far one can take this though.